# CDF in Probability

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
C & \text { for }-3 \leq x<3 \\
Dx & \text { for } 3 \leq x<5 \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.$$

Given that $P(-3 \leq x < 3) = \frac{2}{3}P(3 \leq x < 5)$, What is the cumulative distribution function $CDF(x)$.

So far I have tried to solve the following:

$P(-3 \leq x < 3) = \frac{2}{3}P(3 \leq x < 5)$

$\int_{-3}^x f(x)dx$ = $\frac{2}{3}  \int_{3}^x f(x)dx$

$\int_{-3}^x (C)dx$ = $\frac{2}{3}  \int_{3}^x (Dx)dx$

$\int_{-3}^x (C)dx$ = $ \frac{2}{3}  \int_{3}^x (Dx)dx$

$ \left[Ax\right]_-3^x $ = $\frac{2}{2*3} \left[D* x^{2}\right]_3^x $

C [3 - (x)] = $ \frac{1}{3} \left [D * (x^{2} - 3^{2}\right] $

(3-x)* C = $ \frac{D*(x^{2} - 3^{2})}{3} $

C = $ -\frac{D*(x + 3)}{3} $

How do I find the values for C and D and then calculate the CDF?

Comment: Hi! The other condition you need is that the probabilities must sum up to 1 - that is the integral of f(x) over the real line must be equal to 1. This gives you the other condition on C, D and you can solve the system. Having said that, I think you need to review from scratch integration; only the first line is correct, everything else is wrong. For example, the x can only be present inside the integral, after you solved them the quantities should only depend on C, D

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-3}^{x}f(t)dt \neq \frac{2}{3} \int_{3}^{x}f(t)dt $,   this need not be true

but

$\int_{-3}^{3}f(x)dx = \frac{2}{3} \int_{3}^{5}f(x)dx $

other equation will be

$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(x)dx = 1 $

Get $C,D$ from above two equations

Finally CDF = $\int_{-\infty }^{x }f(t)dt$

Comment: But the first equation is given to be true?

Comment: Its the probabilities that are equal: the total areas under the curves are equal. Not the sum upto some given arbitrary point.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(x)dx = 1 $ will be
$\int_{-3}^3 (C)dx +  \int_{3}^5 (Dx)dx$ = 1 ?

Comment: Yes the integral reduces to that.

Comment: Okay and the last equation I didn't understand that

Comment: That is the expression of CDF by definition.